# Pygame doesn't change font

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I'm trying to change the font that's being used on my Pygame project.
So I've tried to use system fonts, like this:

```
pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 24)
```

Nothing changed. Pygame still using the default ugly font.
I tried to run `pygame.font.get_fonts()` but the result is `[None]` on my Mac.

So I tried to use a custom font, like this:

```
font_small = pygame.font.Font('fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 24)
```

Nothing changes. Still the same font and there's no Exception saying that it wasn't able to open the file. I've tried even to use `os.path.abspath()` to get the full path, with no success.

Any sugestion?

**UPDATE**

I created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thiagodroz/3f5ade4983cfe65bd46a11b719dcdb6f) to test all possibilities.
I had success rendering a font from a ttf file. The solution were to change the second parameter `antialias` from `False` to `True`.

But I still don't understand why I'm not being able to use my System Fonts.

Comment: How are you creating text?

Comment: It looks like there's [an open bug](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/399) loading fonts on macos. Can you show us a [mcve] of your problem trying to use custom fonts?

Comment: I updated the question with some informations and a gist with a simple code

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use this function. Don't forget the instructions *fontobj.render* and *mySurf.blit*

```py
def textePyGame(texte, x, y, mySurf):
    FONDBLEU  = (124, 210, 249, 100)
    ROUGE = (250, 0, 0, 255)
    fontobj = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold",22,bold=False,italic=False)
    text = fontobj.render(texte, True, ROUGE, FONDBLEU)
    larg, ht = fontobj.size(texte)
    mySurf.blit(text,(x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    return ht
```

You can test the loading of the font with
if not pygame.font: print('Attention, polices désactivées')

I hope it will help you